# Customization of color picker extjs 3.4

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I've been trying to customize my **extjs** colorpicker, but not going well till now. I'm using extjs widget. Whenever I want to select any color from colorpicker it changes my text box bg-color and text color, which I need to customize. here how it loos like,

[image]

Is there any way to change the selected color only for the box instead of the whole textbox, using old version of extjs, no helpful documentation found over internet for this. here is my code:

```
<div class="ui-block-item">
    <div class="ui-item">
    <div class="ui-label">
      <?php echo "Label";?>
    </div>
<div class="class">
<div class="xyz " widget="colorpickerfield" name="color-field" width="110" resetValue="FFFFFF">
</div><div class="bg-color-check" id="color-box">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you give your existing code so we can check and work around that. That will also give clear idea about your specific customization.

Comment: @UDID i've edited my question, btw I've solve the issue using css and js. But can't able to customize the colorpickerfield :(.